# Using windows version an linux version of mongodb in the same Replica set

Tags: mongodb

Is it safe to use windows version an linux version of mongodb in the same Replica set or Sharding?

Is it possible to make problem, later?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that problems exist later. You are running two different file systems and they might perform differently meaning that you get replication lag or other oddities.

However, for the most part, I don't see why you can't experiment to see if it works. Any problems are totally theoretical.